# How to disable logging in imported libraries?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, slack, slack-api

In my application, I am using SLF4J's `Logger` for logging. When an error is logged, I am sending a message to another application. The problem is that one of the libraries I use (Slack API) uses the same logger (in class `com.slack.api.methods.impl.TeamIdCache`), so when it logs an error, my application sends a message that I didn't intend it to send.

How can I disable that library's logger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable specific logger in your application properties:

```
logging.level.com.slack.api.methods.impl.TeamIdCache=OFF
```

See [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.logging) for more information regarding other configuration options and log levels.

Comment: Thank you, and one more question. Does `logging.level.com.slack.api.methods=OFF` turn off all loggers from that package? Wouldn't that be better?

Comment: Yes, `logging.level.com.slack.api.methods=OFF` disables all loggers from package `com.slack.api.methods`. If that would be better - it depends on your use case. With this configuration you won't see any logs from that package.